# Android Studio 4.1.3 : Attributes editor “No component selected”

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-20.04

Attributes editor says “No component selected” even when views are selected on Ubuntu 20.04.
The problem seems to exist across different projects. I have already tried rebuilding project / invalidating cache and reinstalling android studio using snap store.

[No component selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1XiL.png)